# Finite ring ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Does a finite ring $R$ may have any other ideal $I$ that satisfies the condition $I \subset R$ except $\langle 0 \rangle$

I could prove that it is the only one ideal $\subset R$ by saying: let $I$ be left ideal, than
$\exists x,y \in R (x \neq y), \forall a \in I, (a \neq 0) \rightarrow (ax = bx) \rightarrow x = y $
But I'm not sure especially the assumption that $(ax = ay) \rightarrow x = y$ when $a \neq 0$

Comment: Yeah, as you guessed, the statement $ax =ay \Rightarrow x=y $ is not true for all rings.

Comment: I'm fond of using $F_2\times F_2$ as a counterexample whenever possible, and it works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Let $I = \langle 3 \rangle$. Then does $I$ satisfy the condition?

Let me add the following: Here we can see that $3 \cdot 2 = 0 = 3 \cdot 4$, but $2 \neq 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Right. And 3x5 = 3x3 here.

Comment: Yeah, you got it now!!! Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that, for $a\ne0$, $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$. Then the map $x\mapsto ax$ is injective and therefore surjective. This implies every $a\ne0$ has a right inverse.

In particular, $R$ is a division ring, because if every nonzero element has a right inverse, then every nonzero element has an inverse: let $a\ne0$; then there exists $b$ so that $ab=1$; since $b\ne0$, there is $c$ so that $bc=1$. Hence
$$
a=a1=a(bc)=(ab)c=1c=c
$$
so also $ba=1$.

A finite division ring is commutative (Wedderburn), so it is a field.

Can you think to a finite ring that's not a field? Hint: if $n>0$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.

Comment: And therefore surjective. But how does it implies that it is surjective - I couldn't figure out

Comment: @AlexeyKhrenov If $f\colon A\to A$ is a map on the *finite* set $A$, then $f$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.